# Messaging Bridge status using WLST

Tags: jms, wlst

I am trying to build a WLST script which tells the state of n number of messaging bridges that I have on AdminServer.

```
connect('uname','pswd','t3://localhost:7001');

serverRuntime();

bd= cmo.getMessagingBridgeRuntime();

print bd.getName();

print bd.getState();
```

I am having issues in finding the mbean instance, error is as follows:

**AttributeError: getMessagingBridgeRuntime**

would be of great help if you already have this script which is working or help me in solving this.

I am using weblogic 10.3.1

Comment: after serverRuntime() command do ls() and check if you see "MessagingBridgeRuntime" in the ls output.

Comment: oops! It's not present, but why it's not present? I need this piece of script to work, any other suggestions?

Comment: It seems that is because of a bug in Weblogic 9.2 till 10.3.5. Check if there are any corresponding patches for your version or follow the alternative suggested at http://wlatricksntips.blogspot.in/2013_04_01_archive.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JMX java code to find the bridge status

```
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.naming.Context;
import java.util.*;

public class GetMessageBridgeStatus {

private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
private static JMXConnector connector;

public static void  getMessageBridgeStatus(String hostname2,String port2,String username2,String password2,String wlname2, List<String> bridgeName) {

    try
    {
        String hostname=hostname2;
        String port=port2;
        String username=username2;
        String password=password2;
        String wlname=wlname2;

        getRuntimeMBeanServerConnection(hostname,port,username,password);

        Iterator<String> iterator = bridgeName.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String bName = iterator.next();

            String bs = "com.bea:ServerRuntime="+wlname+",Name="+bName+",Type=MessagingBridgeRuntime,Location=" +wlname;
            ObjectName service = new ObjectName(bs);

            String status = connection.getAttribute(service,"State").toString();

            String description = connection.getAttribute(service,"Description").toString();

            System.out.println("Name: "+bName+" ::: Status: "+status +" ::: Description: "+description);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void getRuntimeMBeanServerConnection(String hostname1,String port1,String username1,String password1)  throws Exception{
    String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
    String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
    String hostname=hostname1;
    String username=username1;
    String password=password1;
    Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(port1);
    int port = portInteger.intValue();

    JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL("t3", hostname, port,jndiroot + mserver);
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,"weblogic.management.remote");
    connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
    connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
}
}
```